# Why Mandrill emails are not sent from development server(localhost)?

Tags: php, email, mandrill

I am using Mandrill API to send email.

I have register my send domain and set my DKIM and SPF record properly inside Mandrill Setting page.

Following is my code that is being used to send email:

```
$template_name = "Test_Schedule_Reminder";
$to_email = "debesh@debeshnayak.com";
$to_name = "Test Email";

$from_email = "contact@debeshnayak.com";
$from_name = "Debesh Nayak";

require_once 'mandrill-api-php/src/Mandrill.php'; //Not required with Composer
try {
    $mandrill = new Mandrill('my-mandrill-api-key');
    $message = array(
            'html' => $html_email_template,
            'subject' => $email_title,
            'from_email' => $from_email,
            'from_name' => $from_name,
            'to' => array(
                    array(
                            'email' => $to_email,
                            'name' => $to_name,
                            'type' => 'to'
                    )
            ),
            'important' => true,
            'track_opens' => true,
            'track_clicks' => true,
            'inline_css' => true,
            'metadata' => array('website' => 'www.debeshnayak.com'),
    );
    $async = false;
    $ip_pool = null;
    $send_at = $utc_class_time;
    $result = $mandrill->messages->send($message, $async, $ip_pool, $send_at);
    print_r($result);
} catch(Mandrill_Error $e) {
    // Mandrill errors are thrown as exceptions
    echo 'A mandrill error occurred: ' . get_class($e) . ' - ' . $e->getMessage();
    // A mandrill error occurred: Mandrill_Unknown_Subaccount - No subaccount exists with the id 'customer-123'
    throw $e;
}
```

I am able to send email when I am sending from my production server.

But when I am trying to send email from localhost I am getting the following error:

```
Mandrill_HttpError - API call to messages/send failed: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
```

So how to avoid this SSL certificate problem when testing mail from localhost using Mandrill API.

Comment: Do check library files of Mandrill and check cURL call that sending out email. And then checked "CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER" parameter of it. Set value to false. It should help you.

Comment: Thanks @GokulShinde. Your reply helped me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Welcome. Added it as answer. Do accept it and upvote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do check library files of Mandrill and search for `cURL` call that sending out email. Check for `"CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER"` parameter of this cURL. Set value to `false`. It should help you.

Answer (score 1):

I have added the following two line inside `call()` function of `Mandrill.php` library file:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
```

And now I am able to send email from my `localhost` using `Mandrill API`.